# R, knitr, chunck and source function

Tags: r, knitr

I try to split my work into three separated files. One **report.Rmd** where the report is written, a **analysis.R** where the analysis is done, and a **function.R** where I can write my functions used in the **analysis.R**

I can call then **function.R** into the **analysis.R** with *source()* and run it in R without problem. I can call the **analysis.R** into **report.Rmd** and generate the plot with a *read_chunk()* at the beginning.

However, every chunck I call that uses a function defined inside **function.R** does not appear in the **report.Rmd**.

Any suggestions (or comments on how to improve my question)?

Comment: I'm not sure what is happening but you could try sourcing your **function.R** at the beginning of your **report.Rmd**. You can use an option for your chunk if you do not want it to appear in the knitted html file.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] that demonstrates how the files are related (what does "call analysis.R into report.Rmd ..." exactly mean?).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments. I was stupid and not source the **function.R** completely. I found the solution (right after posting my question, sorry about that). I need to source the **function.R** inside **report.Rmd** and call that chunk inside the **report.Rmd** before calling the chunks that use the function.